# Single ErrorDocument directive to catch all errors (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

Is there something like a wildcard directive to catch all possible errors and deal with them in a single custom error page?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?code=404
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?code=403
...
ErrorDocument NNN /error.php?code=NNN #possible use of RegExp?
```

I know I probably won't be dealing with a lot of custom error pages here, but I'm curious about this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is not possible. You need to have a `ErrorDocument` directive for each status code you want to handle differently than with the default error handler.

Comment: Alright, kind of figured - I tried using some of the "tricks" usable on RewriteRule directives, but they only gave 500 errors. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I guess this hasn't changed over the last years?! Also no "ErrorDocument 5** "-Option or similar?!

Answer (score 8):

### **For full reference... As far as i could get...**

First - [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) formatted

Second - Descriptions.

All these i found here -> [httpstatuses.com](https://httpstatuses.com/)

These are All codes - Not just Errors
.. Some will break your site. .

Use like:

```
ErrorDocument 100 https://EXAMPLE.com
```

This is the exact copy Paste.. It is not mine, however i reformatted the list.

---

<sup>*( Hover for description, Click for detail. )*</sup>

**1×× : *Informational***

• [**100**](https://httpstatuses.com/100) : Continue
• [**101**](https://httpstatuses.com/101) : Switching Protocols
• [**102**](https://httpstatuses.com/102) : Processing

---

**2×× : *Success***

• [**200**](https://httpstatuses.com/200) : OK
• [**201**](https://httpstatuses.com/201) : Created
• [**202**](https://httpstatuses.com/202) : Accepted
• [**203**](https://httpstatuses.com/203) : Non-Authoritative Information
• [**204**](https://httpstatuses.com/204) : OK (No Content)
• [**205**](https://httpstatuses.com/205) : Reset Content
• [**206**](https://httpstatuses.com/206) : Partial Content
• [**207**](https://httpstatuses.com/207) : Multi-Status
• [**208**](https://httpstatuses.com/208) : Already Reported
• [**226**](https://httpstatuses.com/226) : IM Used

---

**3×× : *Redirection***

• [**300**](https://httpstatuses.com/300) : Multiple Choices
• [**301**](https://httpstatuses.com/301) : Moved Permanently
• [**302**](https://httpstatuses.com/302) : Found
• [**303**](https://httpstatuses.com/303) : See Other
• [**304**](https://httpstatuses.com/304) : Not Modified
• [**305**](https://httpstatuses.com/305) : Use Proxy
• [**307**](https://httpstatuses.com/307) : Temporary Redirect
• [**308**](https://httpstatuses.com/308) : Permanent Redirect

---

**4×× : *Client Error***

• [**400**](https://httpstatuses.com/400) : Bad Request
• [**401**](https://httpstatuses.com/401) : Unauthorized
• [**402**](https://httpstatuses.com/402) : Payment Required
• [**403**](https://httpstatuses.com/403) : Forbidden
• [**404**](https://httpstatuses.com/404) : Not Found
• [**405**](https://httpstatuses.com/405) : Method Not Allowed
• [**406**](https://httpstatuses.com/406) : Not Acceptable
• [**407**](https://httpstatuses.com/407) : Proxy Authentication Required
• [**408**](https://httpstatuses.com/408) : Request Timeout
• [**409**](https://httpstatuses.com/409) : Conflict
• [**410**](https://httpstatuses.com/410) : Gone
• [**411**](https://httpstatuses.com/411) : Length Required
• [**412**](https://httpstatuses.com/412) : Precondition Failed
• [**413**](https://httpstatuses.com/413) : Request Entity Too Large
• [**414**](https://httpstatuses.com/414) : Request-URI Too Long
• [**415**](https://httpstatuses.com/415) : Unsupported Media Type
• [**416**](https://httpstatuses.com/416) : Requested Range Not Satisfiable
• [**417**](https://httpstatuses.com/417) : Expectation Failed
• [**418**](https://httpstatuses.com/418) : I'm a teapot
• [**422**](https://httpstatuses.com/422) : Unprocessable Entity
• [**423**](https://httpstatuses.com/423) : Locked
• [**424**](https://httpstatuses.com/424) : Method Failure
• [**426**](https://httpstatuses.com/426) : Upgrade Required
• [**428**](https://httpstatuses.com/428) : Precondition Required
• [**429**](https://httpstatuses.com/429).") : Too Many Requests
• [**431**](https://httpstatuses.com/431) : Request Header Fields Too Large
• [**444**](https://httpstatuses.com/444) : No Response
• [**451**](https://httpstatuses.com/451) : Unavailable For Legal Reasons
• [**499**](https://httpstatuses.com/499) : Client Closed Request

---

**5×× : *Server Error***

• [**500**](https://httpstatuses.com/500) : Internal Server Error
• [**501**](https://httpstatuses.com/501) : Not Implemented
• [**502**](https://httpstatuses.com/502) : Bad Gateway
• [**503**](https://httpstatuses.com/503) : Service Unavailable
• [**504**](https://httpstatuses.com/504) : Gateway Timeout
• [**505**](https://httpstatuses.com/505) : HTTP Version Not Supported
• [**506**](https://httpstatuses.com/506) : Variant Also Negotiates
• [**507**](https://httpstatuses.com/507) : Insufficient Storage
• [**508**](https://httpstatuses.com/508) : Loop Detected
• [**510**](https://httpstatuses.com/510) : Not Extended
• [**511**](https://httpstatuses.com/511) : Network Authentication Required
• [**599**](https://httpstatuses.com/599) : Network connect timeout error

*<sub><sup>([Source](https://httpstatuses.com/))</sup></sub>*

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @gadget-guru you inspired me to build a script to test all errors and built this `.htaccess` file to catch all errors at once.

```
ErrorDocument 400 /
ErrorDocument 401 /
ErrorDocument 402 /
ErrorDocument 403 /
ErrorDocument 404 /
ErrorDocument 405 /
ErrorDocument 406 /
ErrorDocument 407 /
ErrorDocument 408 /
ErrorDocument 409 /
ErrorDocument 410 /
ErrorDocument 411 /
ErrorDocument 412 /
ErrorDocument 413 /
ErrorDocument 414 /
ErrorDocument 415 /
ErrorDocument 416 /
ErrorDocument 417 /
ErrorDocument 422 /
ErrorDocument 423 /
ErrorDocument 424 /
ErrorDocument 426 /
ErrorDocument 428 /
ErrorDocument 429 /
ErrorDocument 431 /
ErrorDocument 451 /
ErrorDocument 500 /
ErrorDocument 501 /
ErrorDocument 502 /
ErrorDocument 503 /
ErrorDocument 504 /
ErrorDocument 505 /
ErrorDocument 506 /
ErrorDocument 507 /
ErrorDocument 508 /
ErrorDocument 510 /
ErrorDocument 511 /
```

this will redirect the user to the main page, but you can choose any page of course. Example:

```
ErrorDocument 511 /error.html
```

**note** that any other error code will break the server causing `HTTP 500`

Answer (score 4):

Rather than passing in the error status code, you can pick it up in your script via the REDIRECT_STATUS environment variable (set by Apache). See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/custom-error.html

Comment: This does not solve the problem of enumerating every error code in `.htaccess`, but useful to know nonetheless

Comment: This is what I'm doing, and the question asks how to make this easier to handle in .htaccess.

Answer (score 3):

I don't found a way to handle all ErrorDocument's with one line. But you dont have to write out all the redirects. You can pass the ErrorCode in PHP with:

```
$response_code = http_response_code()
```

My .htaccess looks like

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 402 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```