# Multiple ErrorDocuments in .HTAccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, errordocument

I have a custom error Document "/error.php?e=ERRORCODE" and in my .htaccess I know I need to do:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
```

But so all error codes redirect to my custom error page, I have done this:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 402 /error.php?e=402
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php?e=405
ErrorDocument 406 /error.php?e=406
ErrorDocument 407 /error.php?e=407
ErrorDocument 408 /error.php?e=408
ErrorDocument 409 /error.php?e=409
ErrorDocument 410 /error.php?e=410
ErrorDocument 411 /error.php?e=411
ErrorDocument 412 /error.php?e=412
ErrorDocument 413 /error.php?e=413
ErrorDocument 414 /error.php?e=414
ErrorDocument 415 /error.php?e=415
ErrorDocument 416 /error.php?e=416
ErrorDocument 417 /error.php?e=417

ErrorDocument 422 /error.php?e=422
ErrorDocument 423 /error.php?e=423
ErrorDocument 424 /error.php?e=424

ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?e=500
ErrorDocument 501 /error.php?e=501
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php?e=502
ErrorDocument 503 /error.php?e=503
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php?e=504
ErrorDocument 505 /error.php?e=505
ErrorDocument 506 /error.php?e=506
ErrorDocument 507 /error.php?e=507
ErrorDocument 508 /error.php?e=508
ErrorDocument 509 /error.php?e=509
ErrorDocument 510 /error.php?e=510
```

And I wanted to know if there was a way to compress all of the above into one line.

Thanks.

Comment: According to another answer on StackOverflow, [this is not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612621/288906), unfortunately