# Change Default Error Catch in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

So my question is similar to the question posed in this page

[Single ErrorDocument directive to catch all errors (.htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611748/single-errordocument-directive-to-catch-all-errors-htaccess)

The above person was trying to get a dynamic error page.

However my question is slightly different (although it may still have the same answer).

I am with a shared web host who displays custom error pages by default with ads on it.  I want errors to result in a real error response without ads.  Do I need to individually do a:

```
 ErrorDocument 404     /404.html
```

For each error?  Or is there a way to just tell it to show a normal error message for all errors?

Is there some type of:

```
ErrorDirective JustOutputErrorInsteadOfRedirecting
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With ErrorDocument directive you can also display Your custom error messeage on the same page.

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry, the page does not exist!"

ErrorDocument 403 "Ohh, you don't have permission to access this page!"


ErrorDocument 410 "Sorry, the page no longer exists"
```

You can also format these messges using html tags

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<h2>Sorry, the page does not exist!</h2>"

ErrorDocument 403 "<h2 style='color:blue'>Ohh, you don't have permission to access this page!</h2>"


ErrorDocument 410 "<p>Sorry, the page no longer exists</p>"
```

The message will appear on the same page.